# How to plot OPTICS clustering results using seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, cluster-analysis, optics-algorithm

I obtained features from 10 images from 2 categories (cats and dogs) using CNN. So I have a (10, 2500) numpy array. I applied the OPTICS clustering algorithm on the array to find which image belongs to which cluster

```
clustering = OPTICS(min_samples=2).fit(train_data_array)
```

Now I'm trying to plot the clusters using `seaborn`

```
sns.scatterplot(data=train_data_array).plot
```

But there's no plot.

Comment: That is not valid syntax for scatterplot. Please read the documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html?highlight=scatterplot#seaborn.scatterplot and  provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues.

1. The object returned by OPTICS only contain the labels, so you need
   to add it to your training data.
2. The training data has 2500 variables, most likely you need to do a dimension reduction to render a 2-D plot.

Below is an example using iris dataset:

```
from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = sns.load_dataset("iris").iloc[:,:4]
```

Peform the clustering like you did:

```
clustering = OPTICS(min_samples=20).fit(df)
```

Perform PCA on this data with 4 variables, return top 2 components:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(df)
```

Add PC scores and clustering results to training data, or you can make a separate data.frame:

```
df['PC1'] = pca.fit_transform(df)[:,0]
df['PC2'] = pca.fit_transform(df)[:,1]
df['clustering'] = clustering.labels_
```

Plot:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x="PC1",y="PC2",hue=df['clustering'])
```

[image]